# Let $A,B,X$ be sets such that $A\cap X= B\cap X= A\cap B$ and $X\cup A\cup B = A\cup B$. Show that $X \subseteq A\cap B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, propositional-calculus

Can someone help with this question? Here's what I've got so far

> Take any $x\in X$. Then..
> $x\in X$
> $ x\in X$ or $x\in A$ or $x\in B$
> $x\in A$ or $x\in B$
> ...
> $x\in A\cap B$.

Where do I go from here? If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great, thanks.

Comment: A few formatting tips: you can use math mode on smaller snippets of text than the whole line, and math mode works in titles. I've made some edits to help with this in your post this time - please keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: Your first line is what you're trying to prove.  In other words, assume $x \in X.$  You want to prove $x \in A \cap B$; in other words, you want to prove for an arbitrary $x \in X$ that $x \in A$ and also $x \in B$.  If you do that, you'll have shown $X \subseteq A \cap B$.

Comment: @RobertShore I understand that, but I'm having trouble actually doing the proof. Where do I go from $x\in A\:or\:x\in B$. It seems like a dead end...

Comment: @Dave That's exactly what I did in my attempt provided above... I don't know where to go from $x\in A\:or\:x\in B$

Comment: If $x\in X$, then $x\in X\cup A\cup B \subseteq A\cup B$. Without loss of generality, suppose $x\in A$. Then $x\in X\cap A$. ... Easy enough to take it from here, yes?

Comment: @Yaya123 You want to always work with an $x \in X$ and then impose additional conditions (such as $x \in A$) on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \in X$, then we know that $x \in X \cup A \cup B = A \cup B$.  That means any arbitrary $x \in X$ must be in either $A$ or $B$.

If $x \in A$, then because we assumed $x \in X$ and we're given that $A \cap X = A \cap B$, we know that $x \in A \cap B$.  Similarly, (remembering that $x \in X$ is arbitrary), if $x \in B$, then again $x \in A \cap B$.  Putting these together, if our arbitrary $x \in X$ also is in $A$ or $B$, we have that $x \in A \cap B$.

But we proved above that any arbitrary $x \in X$ must be in at least one of $A$ or $B$, so that means any $x \in X$ must be in $A \cap B$, and that, in turn, means $X \subseteq A \cap B$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x\in X$ we have $x\in A\cup B$ so $x\in A$ or $x\in B$, which you have so far. The next step would be to use the other bit of information we're given.

Let's assume we're in the case with $x\in A$. We started with $x\in X$, so we have $x\in X\cap A$.....